# Ecore file's dialect

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-emf

I have a tool (Enterprise Architect) which can export an Ecore file.

I want to import the generated Ecore in the Eclipse Modeling Framework. But EMF indicates a lot of errors with the generated Ecore file.

I think I need to refactor the generated Ecore file, my question now is:

What kind of dialect / language is the Ecore ?! Is it a XMI, XML Scheme, or what is it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best you visit [this site](http://www.eclipse.org/modeling/emf/) for some background information.  A `*.ecore` file is an `XMI serialization` of the Ecore model.